# Does anyone have a copy of Salce's paper "Cotorsion theories for abelian groups"?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

The paper "Cotorsion theories for abelian groups" by L. Salce, was published in 1979 in Symposia Math. 21, pages 1-21. According to [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.cl/scholar?cluster=2686648928966008225&hl=en&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5), it's been cited 233 times, and I keep seeing citations of this paper as fundamental to cotorsion pairs. But I can't find it anywhere online, or in my library. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The volume and page numbers you give don't seem to agree with mathscinet: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=565595

Comment: it's not online because of copyright restrictions; [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Symposia-Mathematica-Nazionale-Matematica-Francesco/dp/B009AJ5BME) sells it used for $30, and you can search for a nearby library using [Worldcat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/symposia-mathematica/oclc/2253604) (I checked my Leiden University library, but unfortunately volume 23 is missing :( --- I also checked on [Hathitrust](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000642038) that indeed Salce's article is in volume 23, but they only give you a limited text search.

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses! I got my citation info from bibliographies of papers. Good to know it's at least possible to buy online. An hour ago, I didn't even see a way to buy it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get [a scanned copy of Salce's paper](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0d9pse8xy8kngzp/salce_cotorsion.pdf?dl=0) thanks to my library's "Document Delivery" service. Dropbox links are not exactly permanent so if anyone would like to rehost this elsewhere, they should feel free to edit this answer.